# PrintDocument in VS can print, but when publish to IIS it cannot print

Tags: c#, iis, printing

How to set IIS so it will be able to print? When I try through VS 2015 it can print, but when I deploy to IIS it cannot print, I use [this link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44330-printing-in-c%23/) to find print code.

it use PrintDocument class for printing, I think it need to setting the permission / registry for IIS to access the printer, but I don't know how to.

Comment: You do realise you're going to print documents on the server running IIS..?

Comment: yes, the application is a web service to print document like atm printer, I already success using VS, but still failed when deploy to IIS

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do would be to create the document on the IIS (.pdf or anything else) and then provide it as a download. So the user can download the document and print afterwards.

Comment: no, it cannot save as PDF first, because it need automatically print after transaction, just like print in ATM, I already able to print frm VS, but still failed frm IIS

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user that the app pool is running under has permissions to access the printer, as it's possibly as simple as that.

You'd probably want to create a new user on the machine to run the app pool under, a standard user would suffice. And then you'd go to the printer properties, and grant that user permissions to the printer you're wanting to use.

(Of course, check that you do want the IIS server to initiate the printing... this might not be an issue if it's an office system.)

Comment: is there any step by step guide lines ho to that? I am confuse